# WPF : Apply a common Style to multiple columns of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I'd like to share the same style to multiple columns of a DataGrid linked to a Binding source. My dataSource is a table of bool, the idea is to change the backcolor of the cell to red or green depending of true or false (simple thing).

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="InOut" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},  Path=Value}" Value="False" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currrent"       Binding="{Binding bool1}"         CellStyle="{StaticResource InOut}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Voltage"        Binding="{Binding bool2}"         CellStyle="{StaticResource InOut}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid>
```

So far it's compiling, no exceptions... but all my columns are green the Style is used, but the Trigger never fired.
In my real application I also need to change the text from True/False to In or Out (as in fact I'm testing ranges) (it's why I use DataGridTextColumn).

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.
Pascal.

Comment: I don't think `Value` is a valid property for binding here

Comment: Right, I've to use Path=Content.Text then it works. Thanks !

Comment: nice :) you also write: "it's compiling, no exceptions". incorrect binding path doesn't throw exceptions. but if the binding doesn't work, the first place to look is Visual Studio Output window. Binding issues (wrong path, type mismatch) are printed there

Comment: Thanks ASh, I'm newby in WPF. I still have to change my text, I try to add <Setter Property="Content" Value="Out"></Setter>  in the DataTrigger, but it's not working (I assumed content will override text).

Comment: for changing text I recomment to create a converter (IValueConverter implementation) and use it in binding `{Binding bool1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverterResourceKey}`. you probably will have to change `Value="False"` in datatrigger to  `Value="Out"`

Comment: ASh, Thanks, I did it with the converter, it works perfectly. Have a nice day :-)